# Error during image creating in meego (kickstart config default.ks does'not exist)

Tags: meego

I'm trying to build a default MeeGo image with the following command, using the terminal in Fedora14 OS:
        sudo mic-image-creator --config=default.ks --format=liveusb --cache=mycache

as explained here: http://wiki.meego.com/image_Creation#Creating_Supported_Image_Types 
under: "Create Liveusb Image Interactively"
But I keep receiving an error: "kickstart config default.ks' does'not exist"
Do you have any idea how to solve this or what's causing it?

Thanks!
Hadass

Comment: Solution: well, i just had to run the same command from the folder where the .ks files were (make sense right?) and it worked